# 50's/60's (?) sci fi movie: exploration spaceship escapes a star's supernova, ends up in another universe after being sucked in a black hole

Tags: story-identification, movie, black-hole

In the early 1970’s I watched a movie on TV as a little kid, about an exploration spaceship that found a red super giant star that was about to go supernova.

They tried to escape and got sucked into a black hole, and ended up in a new universe with a shot of stars shot with star filters.

It's not the Disney movie *The Black Hole* or *Supernova* (2000).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_(2000_film) matches, but much later.

Comment: Thanks but sadly much later, I’m afraid. But thanks anyway.

Comment: When you say "It's not the Disney movie," that's unclear. Disney has made a lot of movies. Did you mean: "It's not the Disney movie *The Black Hole*"?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I meant, sorry I was unclear.

Comment: @JohnMann I just now saw your comment confirming which Disney science fiction movie you meant, and then I decided to go ahead and insert that movie title into your post to make it clear.

Answer (score 6):

*Into Infinity*, also known as *The Day After Tomorrow* (1976), a British TV special?

Apart from it being made in the 70s, the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_(TV_special)) seems to match your description:

> **A fail-safe brings the vessel, now powerless, to a halt within the gravitational field of a red giant on the brink of supernova**. Donning a heat suit, Captain Masters risks his life by entering the reactor core in a bid to repair the drive. He succeeds, and **Anna and Jane pilot the ship outside the blast radius of the star before it explodes.**
>
> Detecting a signal from Delta, which has taken the equivalent of 15 Earth years to reach them, the travellers are able to plot their position and lay in a course home. However, **disaster strikes when Altares is caught in the gravity of a black hole that has formed from a collapsed star.** [...]
>
> Her theory is proven correct when, sustaining the various space-time distortions at the event horizon, Altares safely emerges from the black hole – intact, albeit with no way of returning to Earth. As the vessel and its intrepid crew approach a planet, the narrator concludes, "One thing is sure – this is not the final word. Not the end, but the beginning. **A new universe, a new hope? Only time will tell.**"

It's on YouTube. Not sure what you mean by "star filters" but the last couple of shots​ does have some generic-looking star shots:

---

Found with the Google query `movie "red giant" "black hole" site:imdb.com/title` which returned [this summary](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2000412/plotsummary#summary-ps3724614).

Comment: This may be it. YouTube has regrettably taken it down, but at least I may now have have a starting point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is it the Space:1999 episode "Black Sun"? It aired in 1975

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This might be a good answer, but it's hard to know, since you've included no details.  You should list the elements of the show that match the question.  Please read [answer].